# AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'

Tags: angular, cordova, azure, cordova-plugins, adal

I use this library https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova , This is how I have written code :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", () => {
let authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/(tenant_id)");
console.log("@login : TokenAsync");
var uri = "&client_secret=(value)";
authContext.acquireTokenAsync((resourceurl), (client_id), (redirecturi), this.vEmail, encodeURI(uri))
.then((res) => {
console.log(res);
console.log("Token acquired: " + res.accessToken);
console.log("Ex acquired: " + res.expiresOn);
}, reject => {
console.log(reject);
}); }, false);
```

i had try using extraQueryParameters to add client_secret, but the error still same :

> AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter:
>   'client_secret or client_assertion'.

how i add the client_secret ? or there's any alternative solution?

Comment: Your app is a public client. You cannot use a client secret, full stop. I have not done a Cordova app before, but you will need to use one of the flows that redirects the user to the login page or pops open a web view with the login page.

Comment: You can check the sample here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova/blob/master/sample/js/index.js

Comment: Oh, your app is registered as a *native app* in AAD right?

Comment: the app is registered as web apps. native app for public client right ? or i have to choose native app ?

Comment: Cordova apps are native apps.

Comment: Code runs on user's device = public client. Code runs on back-end server = non-public client. Public clients can't use client secrets since they cannot secure them.

Answer (score 1):

> AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.

According to your mentioned exception, I assume that you registry the web app/API application. As junas mentioned that please have a try to use an AAD native app  then it should work. More details you could refer to this [document -Constraints & Limitations section](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/).

> No web sites/confidential clients
>
> This is not an ADAL limitation, but an AAD setting. You can only use those flows from a native client. A confidential client, **such as a web site, cannot use direct user credentials**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **advanced setting** of the default client type. Just switch here from No to **Yes** and it works.

[image]